# In TypeScript, is there a way to omit a type of true or false?

Tags: typescript

This was my best attempt at trying this. Is it possible or even necessary? Maybe there is something I'm missing about typescript that makes more sense.

```
const TrueOrFalse = True | False;

const OnlyTrue = Omit<TrueOrFalse, false>;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Omit` removes properties from an object type. What you want to do is exclude a type from a union. You can do this with the built-in conditional type `Exclude`.

```
type X = Exclude<boolean, true> // X is false
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=46&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAGlC8UCiAPAxgGwK4BMIB4AjAe2IwgEMA7AGimACcsIA+KAendigEsBnKADMKGPhCA)

`Exclude` will take out of the first type parameter, any type that is a subtype of the second parameter.

You can read more about exclude [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetu)

`Exclude` and its cousin `Extract` can be useful also in manipulating discriminated unions, to extract or exclude a specific constituent from a union, even if you only know the discriminant not the whole the type:

```
type Shape = { type: "sq", size: number } | { type: "circle", radius: number }


type Square = Exclude<Shape, { type: "circle" }> //  { type: "sq", size: number }
type Circle = Extract<Shape, { type: "circle" }> //  { type: "circle", radius: number }
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAygFgQ0lAvFA3lUkBcUBEAzgI74A0UhAlgF4R4B2ArgLYBGEATlAL5QA+GLOHoEAxlU5iANhHJROCACZUmhRqw7ceAKD3ZoMYkwSdoaAKIAPGUyUQAPPCQQKmA3nwSps-LwB8UAD0QVBCHgQk8tR0GuxcvDoGUADCkjLmUNbAimLAToiQbsK44um+AcGh4SKe3hnyiipqcVq8UEA)